# Access denied copying or interacting with .msi packages

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Im attempting to robocopy a directory tree to another location on the same disk, on my Windows 2008R2 enterprise file server.

My powershell script calls robocopy, and copies most of the contents of the directory tree without any issues, except when it encounters a .msi package, whereby robocopy will return an "access denied"

I am logged on, and running the powershell as my domain admin account.
UAC is disabled on this machine, I believe therefore "run as administrator" is not required. (Also tried running as admin, made no difference)

The folder and the file within has full control set via membership of the COMPUTERNAME\administrators group.
This group is also the owner of the file.

I am also unable to copy the .msi package from the source to destination in the gui using copy/paste.
[image]

I cannot find any Deny ACLS set on this folder, or on the file Im copying, or folder Im copying to.
I can copy other types of files, just not MSI files.

Can anyone shed any light?

Answer (score 0):

File screening for .msi files was switched on. DOH.